# Systax error in Insert statement with oledb.12.0

Tags: vba, ms-access, oledb

this is my first question
When I click button2 I get an error
The error statement is like this
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

```
Public Class 회원가입
    Dim dbConn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    Dim selectCom As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Dim insertCom As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Dim dbDa As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    Private Sub db_connection()
        dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bsa05\Documents\team\Vb_project\Team_project_c\Team_project_c\c조회원가입.accdb"
        dbConn.Open()
        selectCom.Connection = dbConn
        selectCom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM userinfo"
    End Sub
    Private Sub db_update()
        dbDa.SelectCommand = selectCom
        dbDa.Fill(C조회원가입DataSet, "userinfo")
        dbDa.Update(C조회원가입DataSet, "userinfo")
        UserinfoTableAdapter.Fill(C조회원가입DataSet.userinfo)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        db_connection()
        insertCom.Connection = dbConn
        insertCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userinfo([ID],[PW])" & "VALUE('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
        insertCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        db_update()
        Me.UserinfoBindingSource.Position = Me.BindingContext(UserinfoBindingSource).Count
        dbConn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub 회원가입_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.UserinfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.C조회원가입DataSet.userinfo)

    End Sub
End Class
```

can somebody help me with this

Comment: Change `"VALUE(` to `" VALUES (`

Comment: omg .... thanks you

Comment: Why do you tag "Oracle" when you use MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle (rather than SQL Server), you don't want the square brackets around the identifiers and you want an `S` on the `VALUES` keyword:

You also should **NOT** be using string concatenation and should be using bind variables ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685293/1509264)):

```sql
insertCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userinfo(ID,PW) VALUES(?, ?)";
insertCom.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = TextBox1.Text; 
insertCom.Parameters.Add("@PW", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = TextBox2.Text;
```

*(Note: The code above is untested and is for example purposes. Please refer to the documentation if the syntax is incorrect. The principle still applies; do **NOT** use string concatenation to build queries, especially when taking user input as it just opens your code to SQL injection attacks.)*